# How to make a regex expression to filter all special symbols?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, unicode, c++11

My IDE is VS 2012, I use C++ 0x. I want to process a Chinese string and replace a word with another, even if the word is split by some special symbols. I enumerated all the special symbols on the keyboard and it works well. The code is like this:

```
std::wstring ws_str = L"性 \t\r\n`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\\|;:'\",<.>/?爱";
std::wregex wrx(L"性[\\s`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+\\[\\{\\]\\}\\|;:'\",<.>/?]*爱");
std::wstring wfmt(L"革命");
std::locale::global(std::locale("chs"));
std::wstring ws_res = std::regex_replace(ws_str, wrx, wfmt);
```

But the above code has its weak points: I can't enumerate all the symbols that are not on the keyboard. Is there any other way I can reach my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

性(\W|_)*爱 can solve my problem, \W means to exclude all characters(including Chinese or other language) and underline symbol '`_`', so I append '`_`' and meet the requirement.